# Why does my Perl server fail to bind to port 80?

Tags: perl, sockets, netstat

I copied the following script and run it to have it listen on port 80. But `netstat` doesn't show port 80.  Why does `netstat` not sow it, or the Perl script is not correct?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Socket;
use IO::Handle; 

$port=80; 
$host='localhost'; 
$packhost=inet_aton($host); 
$address=sockaddr_in($port,$packhost); 

socket(SERVER,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname('tcp')); 
bind(SERVER,$address); 
listen(SERVER,10); 

while( 1 ) {
    next unless (accept(CLIENT,SERVER)); 
    CLIENT->autoflush(1); 
    $msg_out="WHAT DO YOU WANT?\n"; 
    send(CLIENT,$msg_out,0); 
    close CLIENT;
} 

close SERVER; 
exit 1;
```

Comment: Can you ping port 80? Try running 'netstat -an' ...

Comment: Port 80 is a privileged port. Are you running the script as root? The return value from bind will be false if it can't bind the port.

Comment: You sure saved a lot of time by omitting error checking.  Oh wait, no.

Comment: Sarcasm is a communication tool known for its effectiveness.  Oh wait, no.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What platform are you on? How are you invoking `netstat`?

On Windows XP, after running the script with admin privileges, <kbd>netstat -a</kbd> gives me:

```
TCP    aardvarkvi:http        aardvarkvi:0           LISTENING
```

Binding to ports below 1024 requires root privileges on `*nix` systems. Since you do not (or, shall I say, code you seem to have blindly copied does not) check the return values of various calls, you would not know if they failed.

In general, you should not have to use Socket.pm. Stick with [IO::Socket](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket) and avoid blindly copying code without knowing what it does.

You might also want to look into [HTTP::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Daemon).

Comment: Your link to HTTP::Daemon is broken (you only put 1 ':', not 2).  The correct URL is:

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Daemon

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-KBD Whoa, are you actually using <kbd> for "Indicates text to be entered by the user", or just because of its visual effect?  :)

Comment: Actually, I used it to 'indicates text to be entered by the user'. The fact that SO styles prominently is a mixed blessing. I would actually find it more pleasing with less of a bevel effect (or whatever it is called ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `netstat` is replacing the numeric port number by the name from `/etc/services`. For example:

```
    ~, 503> netstat -a | more
    Active Internet connections (servers and established)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
    tcp        0      0 *:svn                   *:*                     LISTEN
```

One thing that you can do is grep `netstat`'s output to find all sockets where it's listening:

```
    netstat -a | grep LISTEN | grep tcp
```

You can also tell `netstat` to show numeric addresses rather than doing a hostname or services lookup (and there's another option where you can limit just port numbers; do <kbd>man netstat</kbd>):

```
    netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, when I run netstat, I didn't put the option -a. When use netstat -a, it shows that port.

Comment: By default, `netstat` only lists connected sockets.  `-a` lists all sockets, and Linux's `netstat` also understands `-l` to list listening sockets.